# mysql stopped and cannot start

Tags: mysql, start

I need some help here (excuse me for my bad English).

mysql stopped suddenly after running for several hour. Since then I'm unable to start it. I have also restarted my computer.
I get the following error message

```
mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
```

What should I do? Any advice?

I'm using xampp 5.6.14.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check, if your disk is full? If yes, then try to free up spaces and start again.

Comment: my disk 14GB free

Comment: Then you need to try repair the corrupt table. See  [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-repair.html)

Answer (score 1):

Stop the mysql service.
navigate to the data library and repair the table

```
mysql myisamchk -r -v -f mysql/<DB_NAME>/<TABLE_NAME>
```

Don't forget to make a backup before trying to repair.

You can find more relative informations in the official documentation : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html

Comment: It is strange that this table has crashed during normal workload, as it's only written on permission change which is a manual process. Before proceeding with *myisamchk* check your disk for errors.